# Scala macros: Get type arguments of root type of object members inside class definition

Tags: scala, scala-macros

A bit of a funky scenario, best outlined below.

Suppose I have `sealed trait Painting[T]`, and then a bunch of more specialised variations, such as `trait ImpressionistPainting[T] extends Painting[T]` and so on, building a simple sealed type family.

I then have a class with a f bounded polymorphic type bound as such:

```
class Gallery[T <: Gallery[T]]()(implicit helper: GalleryHelper[T])
```

And a:

```
trait GalleryHelper[T <: Gallery[T]] {
  def paintings: Set[Painting[_]]
}
object GalleryHelper {
  implicit def materialize[T <: Gallery[T]]: GalleyHelper[T] = {
    macro MyMacro.materialize[T]
  }

  def apply[T <: Gallery[T]]()(
   implicit ev: GalleryHelper[T]
  ): GalleryHelper[T] = ev 
}
```

So far this is very basic and straightforward foo bar code.

The whole goal of this setup is to macro materialise a helper list of items that I need to describe the gallery, or in this case arbitrarily typed "user content", as such:

```
class MyGallery extends Gallery[MyGallery] {
  object `le-reve` extends CubistPainting[Picasso]
  object starry_night extends PostImpressionistPainting[VanGogh]
  // ..
}
```

Now with some macro compat fun, I want to macro materialise the helper in question and filter the members of `T <: Gallery[T]` to extract those which are `MemberType <:< Painting[_]`.

All very straightforward, the below is more complex than simply `type.decls.filter(_.typeSignature <:< typeOf[Filter]` because it needs to return a list of all inherited members in the order they are written as well, given galleries extend other galleries for instance.

```
  def findMembersWithBound[T : WeakTypeTag, Filter : TypeTag](
    exclusions: Symbol => Option[Symbol] = { s: Symbol => Some(s) }
  ): Set[Symbol] = {
    val tpe = weakTypeOf[T].typeSymbol.typeSignature

    (
      for {
        baseClass <- tpe.baseClasses.reverse.flatMap(exclusions(_))
        symbol <- baseClass.typeSignature.members.sorted
        if symbol.typeSignature <:< typeOf[Filter]
      } yield symbol
    )(collection.breakOut)
  }
```

So in an implicit macro, a basic traversal of module members for type T would need to filter by a sub type, in this case `Painting[_]`, and then look at what specific type arguments where provided by the user when extending a variant of `Painting`. The type family is sealed, so users extend a sub class of `Painting` with `object`, never `Painting[_]` directly, if this is relevant in any way.

```
@macrocompat.bundle
class MyMacro(val c: blackbox.Context) {
  import c.universe._
  def materialize[T <: Gallery[T]]: Tree = {
    val galleryTpe = weakTypeOf[T]
    val fields = findMembersWithBound[T, Painting[_]](exclusions)

    val colMembers = sourceMembers.map { member =>
      val memberType = member.typeSignatureIn(galleryTpe)

      memberType.baseClasses.find(colSymbol ==) match {
        case Some(root) => {
          // Herein lies the problem, typeArgs is Nil.
          root.typeSignatureIn(memberType).typeArgs.headOption match {
            case Some(colSignature) => colSignature
            case None => c.abort(
              c.enclosingPosition,
              s"Could not find the artist for ${member.asModule.name}"
          )
        }
      }
      case None => c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, s"Could not find root painting type for ${member.asModule.name}")
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that none of the original type arguments passed through to `Painting` are visible anymore, even though the `typeSignature` would apper to be evaluated in scope and so on, and I'm simply trying to make sure Van Gogh doesn't become the proverbial Waldo.

What is the correct API to `dealias` or however else make those `typeArgs` visible again? Currently an empty list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok turns out there's a "well hidden" way to do this using `asSeenFrom`. The relevant part is:

```
root.typeSignature.typeParams match {
  case head :: Nil => head.asType.toType.asSeenFrom(memberType, colSymbol)
  case _ => c.abort(
    c.enclosingPosition,
   "Expected exactly one type parameter provided for painting type"
  )
}
```